# Split the equation into three lines because it is too long

Tags: equations, multline

How can I split the following equation that goes beyond the margin?

```
\begin{align}
f_4(s)=\\
 \sum_{i=0}^{\Delta_1-1}{\frac{1}{i!}[(-s)^i  \frac{\delta^i}{\delta(s)^i}(\exp(-s^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} \lambda_1 (\eta_1 P_1)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}C(\alpha,\psi_1))
(\exp(-s^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} \lambda_2 (\eta_2 P_2)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}C(\alpha,\psi_2))}
\label{eq17}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As the code stands, there will be two equation numbers. Is it really what you want?

Comment: I suggest a label that's more informative than `eq17` since it might not be equation 17 as you revise the document.

Answer (score 4):

Using `multline` you can just use `\\` to change line.

```
\begin{multline}
f_4(s)=\sum_{i=0}^{\Delta_1-1}\frac{1}{i!}
\Big[
(-s)^i \frac{\delta^i}{\delta(s)^i}
\Big( \exp(-s^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} \lambda_1 (\eta_1 P_1)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}C(\alpha,\psi_1) \Big)  \\
\Big( \exp(-s^{\frac{2}{\alpha}} \lambda_2 (\eta_2 P_2)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}C(\alpha,\psi_2) \Big)
\Big] 
\label{eq17}
\end{multline}
```

[image]